# date_diff() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeInterface, string given

Tags: php, datediff

when i am trying to execute this getting error like   date_diff() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeInterface, string given

```
    $date2=date_create("2017-03-15");
    date_format($date2,"Y/m/d");
    $date1=date('Y/m/d');
    $diff=date_diff($date2,$date1);
    echo $diff;
```

Answer (score 1):

Both variables should be in the same format. Just try this:

```
$date2=date_create("2017-03-15");
$date1=date_create(date('Y-m-d'));
$diff=date_diff($date2,$date1);
echo $diff->days;
```

Comment: even i tried this also getting error                                                 
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\date_dif.php on line 6

Comment: Cause result is an object, so you can't just echo object. I've fixed code to display diff in days.